# Multiple selectors: unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select a hidden field in order to remove it. I want to select it by type, a custom data attribute and by name. My selector looks like:

```
$("input[type=hidden] data-supplied='Cola' name='companies[\"4425506\"]'").remove();
```

This is giving me the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=hidden data-supplied='Cola' name='companies["4425506"]']
```

Any idea of whats wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why people like to bully and downvote when you don't know something... Isnt that the point of stackoverflow?

Comment: People don't generally downvote to be bullies, or because you don't know something, it just means that they think your question isn't useful (too vague, off-topic, etc).

I actually think this is a useful question, I'm just saying that you shouldn't take it personally if you get downvoted on the internet. =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to match multiple attributes. This works just like matching one attribute; just add as many `[name=value]` selectors as you like, not separated by anything:

```
   input[type=hidden][data-supplied='Cola'][name='companies[\"4425506\"]']
```

Your code becomes:

```javascript
$("input[type=hidden][data-supplied='Cola'][name='companies[\"4425506\"]']")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you select multiple attributes. ([See jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/))

```
 $("input[type=hidden][data-supplied='Cola'][name='companies[\"4425506\"]']");
```

However, I would recommend adding a class to your html:

```
<input[type=hidden] data-supplied='Cola' name='companies[\"4425506\"]' class="tada" />
```

Then enjoy readable javascript:

```
$("tada").remove();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but to explain a little bit better my question. I have a lot of hidden fields, thats why I'm trying to select just that one. I dont think a class would work.

Comment: It does. That's why i voted up. Will have to approve Salman cause he gave the answer first though...